# Excel - i need first non-blank value of a column

Tags: excel

This is my Column. I need the 2.46 in cell b1 how do i do that?

```
A1 ---- BLANK
A2 ---- BLANK
A3 ---- BLANK
A4 ---- 2.46
A5 ---- BLANK
A6 ---- BLANK
A7 ---- BLANK
A8 ---- BLANK
A9 ---- 2.58
A10 ---- BLANK
A11 ---- BLANK
A12 ---- BLANK
```

Comment: i need first non-blank value of a column. This is a moving Column. Moving every second towards A12 and 2.46 will be disappear too.

Comment: Is the 2.46 always the smallest number in the range? If so, `=MIN(A1:A12)` works too

Answer (score 3):

Try this formula

`=INDEX(B1:B100,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(B1:B100<>"",0),0))`

extend ranges as required